# Equinumerosity: A Bijection Existence Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, cardinals

I'm told that if $m<n$, then the intervals $(0,1)$ and $(m,n)$ are equinumerous.

I'm asked to prove this by exhibiting a specific bijection between them. I came up with this:
$$f(x)=(n-m)x+m,\quad\text{for $0<x<1$}.$$

Is this a good function to choose?

Comment: It's one of the best.

Comment: Lovely, linear.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Should I show that it is a bijection?

Comment: Yes, I think you are expected to show that this is a bijection between the two intervals.

Comment: Yes, it is geometrically obvious, but the game here is to do all details.

Comment: So $f(x)=f(x')\implies x=x'$, but how do I show $f((0,1))\rightarrow (m,n)$? @AndréNicolas

Comment: How about finding its inverse explicitly?

Comment: Two parts. (i) show that if $0\lt x\lt 1$, then $m\lt f(x)\lt n$, minor work with inequalities: (ii) Show that if $y\in (m,n)$ there is an $x\in(0,1)$ such that $f(x)=y$. It is easy to find, by inverting, what $x$ should work.

Comment: So $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x+m}{n-m}$, and so the existence of the inverse implies the bijectivity of $f$.

Comment: *Equine-merousness* ... something to do with horses...

Comment: @Trancot: Actually, $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x-m}{n-m}$. Also, to be thorough, you should prove both $x=f(f^{-1}(x))$ and $x=f^{-1}(f(x))$.

Comment: @GEdgar Drunken horses (Latin "merum" = "wine")

Answer (score 1):

As the main question has already been answered in the comments, here's a summary:

Yes, this is a good function to use.  Because we can explicitly write the inverse as a function, we know that $f$ is a bijection.